# Spinner in Custom Function for Android with java

Tags: java, android

I am confused about calling the spinner widget through a custom function. I am create an app in which I use spinner 20-35 times a spinner widget in single layout or activity. So for this  i want to avoid the spinner code repetition again and again. i am creating a method for this i add the items to the spinner but i want to pass item value on select to other activity which bind to that class

**Here is my code**

**Spin_tester.class**

```
public class Spin_tester {
    public String result;
    public Context ctx;

    public Spin_tester(Spinner spinner, final ArrayList<String> arraylist, final Context ctx , final String value) {
        this.ctx= ctx;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adpts =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arraylist);         
        spinner.setAdapter(adpts);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                  
                result = arraylist.get(position);
                value = result ;      // This is not working
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Test_Activity.class**

```
public class Test_Activity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    ArrayList<String> data_list = new ArrayList<>();
    Spinner spins;
    String value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        spins = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        data_list.add("1");
        data_list.add("2");
        data_list.add("3");
        data_list.add("4");

        Spin_tester asd = new Spin_tester(spins,data_list,this,value);
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    }
}
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Java is a pass-by-value language, not pass-by-reference. What this means is that setting **value** in `setOnItemSelectedListener` will only change **value** within that method — the result won't be passed back anywhere.

I see that you've place the result in **result**. That is where the calling program will find the answer.

Remove all instances of **value** from Spin_tester and Test_Activity and then have your main activity get the result from `asd.result`

---

I'm going to get a little meta at this point: I've only answered the question you actually asked, but this code is wrong on so many levels that you're never going to get it to work. I strongly suggest you work your way through the examples and tutorials in the documentation before you try to proceed any further.